# Ruby rufus scheduler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduling

We're thinking about using the rufus-scheduler gem on a Ruby on Rails project to do regular monitoring of a communication queue.  Has anyone have experience using this gem on a Rails project?  Anyone have strong preferences of an alternative scheduler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find cron and script/runner is usually enough, but I don't think you'll really go wrong with rufus-scheduler.

Just make sure the scheduled tasks you're running are sufficiently abstracted so that if you decide to change your mind later on about how these tasks are run, it isn't a big problem.

I say experiment and run with it if you like it.